# How do i get the golden BASS guitar in Rockband 2?

Tags: rock-band-2

So i have the golden guitar, but forgot how I got it. Anyone know what setlist you play to get the bass version?

Comment: You get the Golden Guitar for winning the Impossible Guitar Challenge, but winning the Impossible Bass Challenge gives you "The Bomb" Bass, if I recall.  I don't know if there is a golden bass, but I've been wrong before :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the Gold BASS, you must complete the Impossible Bass Challenge.

A list of instrumental unlocks can be seen [here](http://www.cheatcc.com/xbox360/rockband2cheatscodes.html) under "Bonus instruments"

> **Gold bass**: Successfully complete the Impossible Bass Challenge.